# 型クラスを表示した時に括弧が表示されない理由

Tags: haskell

『すごいHaskell』を読みながら本にあるコードを入力していっているのですが

```
ghci> :t (==)
(==) :: (Eq a) => a -> a -> Bool
```

と型クラスで表示されると本にあったものが
実際にコンソールで入力してみると

```
ghci> :t (==)
(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool
```

と`Eq q`が括弧で囲まれていない状態で表示されました。

特に気にしなくてもいいかとも思ったのですが、
括弧の有無が厳密な言語なので
もしこの表記の違いの理由を知ってる方がいたら教えて下さい。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

カッコが必須なのは、制約を2つ以上書くときです。

例えば、GHCiで `:i (,)` を実行すると、下記のように`(a, b)`の`Eq`型クラスのインスタンスは、`a`と`b`両方が`Eq`のインスタンスでないといけないので、それを表現するためにカッコで囲って`Eq a`と`Eq b`を列挙しています。

```
ghci> :i (,)
...

instance (Eq a, Eq b) => Eq (a, b) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’

...
```

Comment: 制約が一つの場合は括弧がoptionalなのでGHCiがどちらの表現を使うかは環境によって変わるという理解であっていますか？

Comment: はい。そうだと思います。